# AppEngine kills JVM instance too fast

Tags: google-app-engine

AppEngine kills my JVM instance really quickly. It does not live longer than 30 seconds idle. Subsequent request will create new instance but this roundtrip takes 8-10 seconds. Is there potential problem (bug) in my application ? There is no record in logs/admin logs which would indicate any problem or reason of shutdown. Development server works normaly. Is there any chance to find out why the instance is shutdown so quickly ?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine especially on free account can kill the instance anytime. Instance can live couple of seconds if idle or couple of minutes, noone knows how long. Should you need resident instance (to prevent long instance start-up), switch to paid version. Even if it is paid, you can still run it for free if you keep your instance hours within free quota. This means if you have single F1 instance, it will consume 24instance-hours per day. As per today quotas, you have free 28instance-hours per day so you have 4 instance-hours spare for app redeployments (every redeployment costs 1/4 of instance-hour or 15 minutes). Having F2 instance will consume quota 2x faster e.g. it will take 14 hours to consume your 28hour free quota. Next 10 hours will be billed to your credit card as per price list.